# Category shows only top level child categories

Tags: categories, children

I have found this code online but it shows all child categories when on parent category:

```
<?php
    $this_category = get_category( $cat );
    $child_categories = get_categories( array( 'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID,'depth' => 1));
    foreach( $child_categories as $category ) { 
        $category_url = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
        $category_name = $category->cat_name; ?>
        <div class="col3">
                <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id, array(365, 165)); ?>">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $category_url?>"><?php echo $category_name?></a></h3>
        </div><?php
    }
```

For example if I have

> ```
> Parent
> -Child
> --Child 2
> ---Child 3
> Parent 2
> ```

When someone clicks on *Child* it should show only *Child 2*. This code now shows both *Child 2* and *Child 3* when someone clicks *Child*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'depth'` is not a parameter for the function `get_categories()`;
to get only direct child categories, try working with `'parent'` instead of `'child_of'`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/